# Scala Actor in script mode

Tags: scala, actor

I'm trying go through Chapter 9 of Programming in Scala, but I found the Actor sample code could not run in script mode.

The code is simple:

```
// TestActor.scala

import scala.actors.Actor

class Redford extends Actor {
  def act() {
    println("A lot of what acting is, is paying attention.")
  }
}

val robert = new Redford
robert.start
```

But when I run `scala TestActor.scala`, nothing happens, the program exit before the Redford class print anything.

But if I use the following code to compile and run, everything works fine, it prints the message as expected.

```
// TestActorCompiled.scala

import scala.actors.Actor

class Redford extends Actor {
  def act() {
    println("A lot of what acting is, is paying attention.")
  }
}

object Main {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val robert = new Redford
    robert.start
  } 
}
```

It seems when the program run in the script mode, it exit before the actor doing anything.

Why this happens? And how could I make this program do no exit before `Actor.act()` is done when the program is running in script mode?

Update:

I'm using Scala 2.8.1.final

Comment: Hmmm... 1st runs fine at 2.8.0.final

Answer (score 0):

Tested on `2.8.1.final`. Strange thing. The first time I run it failed with:

```
Could not connect to compilation daemon.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: fsc failure
        at scala.tools.nsc.CompileSocket.fatal(CompileSocket.scala:50)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CompileSocket.getPort(CompileSocket.scala:122)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CompileSocket.getsock$1(CompileSocket.scala:152)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CompileSocket.getOrCreateSocket(CompileSocket.scala:170)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$.compileWithDaemon(ScriptRunner.scala:145)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$.compile$1(ScriptRunner.scala:197)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:225)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:265)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:91)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

The second time it passed successfully:

```
>scala TestActor.scala
A lot of what acting is, is paying attention.
```